# Upgrade log4j in apache jmeter core maven

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I'm fairly new to maven, so bear with me.

I have this dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

These dependencies contain log4j version `2.11.2` and i want to update them to atleast 2.17.1 (i think thats the latest version, not sure).

Is there a way to explicitly update these version numbers, as `5.4.3` is the latest version of jmeter core and its not log4j compliant.

I use the plugin

```
<groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
```

and that isnt updating to `5.4.3` either. i kinda need some help making this jmeter code log4j compliant.

Comment: As far as I can see these both depend on 2.17 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core/5.4.3

Comment: the dependency graph says it has 2.11.2 though? how do i get that version @BoristheSpider

Comment: Something else is overriding the version would be my guess - find that thing.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yeh thats what i thought. is there a way to override all log4j versions and use a specific one?

Comment: No. Maven uses “closest”  version resolution so you can perhaps hack something.

Comment: @BoristheSpider sorry im fairly new with maven so any code help would be appreciated. how do i hack the version?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dependency as dependency-management in your POM.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-artifactid</artifactId>
      <version>${log4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Or the BOM. But it needs be to in the right order - if there are other items in the dependency management section then order matters.

Answer (score 0):

1. `jmeter-maven-plugin` version [`3.1.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/3.1.0)  will give you JMeter 5.3 no matter what you specify in the `<dependencies>` section.
2. The latest version is [3.5.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lazerycode.jmeter/jmeter-maven-plugin/3.5.0) which gives you JMeter 5.4.1

So you will either need to wait for the next release or to explicitly specify the desired JMeter version like:

```
<configuration>
    <jmeterVersion>5.4.3</jmeterVersion>
</configuration>
```

Full *pom.xml* just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Generate JMeter configuration -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>configuration</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>configure</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterVersion>5.4.3</jmeterVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)